# How to provide a json feed which contain an array of views?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a view for an *project*. When I do an Ajax call on the method *showProjects()* in my ProjectController, I would get a json feed which contain an array of templates for each item.

Actually, I try that, but I get a json feed which contain *request objects* , not the templates. I don't want to display one template with each item, because I want to process them in js.

```
#ProjectController.php

public function showProjects() {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $projects = $em->getRepository('BtaskBoardBundle:Project')->findAll();
    if (!$projects) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    }

    $projects_template = array();
    foreach ($projects as $project) {
        $projects_template[] = $this->render('MyBundle::project.html.twig', array(
            'project' => $project,
            ));
    }

    return new Response(json_encode($projects_template), 200);
}

#project.html.twig

<a class="project" data-id="{{ project.id }}" href="#">{{ project.name }}</a>
```

What's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response object you get back should have a `getContent()` method. Check out the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` class in the [documentation](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/) for more information. You should be able to do it like so:

```
foreach ($projects as $project) {
    $projects_template[] = $this->render('MyBundle::project.html.twig', array(
        'project' => $project,
        ))->getContent();
}
```

Comment: It's working. Is there a better way to do that in stead to do an ugly foreach in showProjects() method?